# Ubuntu shutdown is very slow

Tags: shutdown, logout, logs

During my daily work with Ubuntu it sometimes happens that shutdown process is very slow. It takes about 10 minutes. But this happens only after about 3-4 hours of continuous work. (If I shutdown right after ubuntu start the shutdown is normal).
What can be the reason? How can I see detailed information what is going on during shut down?

The `syslog` file contains a little information and I cannot see what causes such delay.

Also sometimes Ubuntu suddenly logs me out. This also happens after 3-4 hrs of work. I think there is a relation between these two issues.

Update. I think that it is slow because some process cannot be stopped/killed. If so, how can I determine which process?

This is the shutdown screen:

[image]

("Killing all remaining processes" fails)

Comment: I don't know, but maybe it's clearing caches and RAM?